# How to find the state of threads in iOS?

Tags: ios, multithreading, time, state, performance

I have implemented some threading functions (I used `NSInvocaionOperation`) that does some background process without interfering the UI response. Everything works well and all the selectors that I added in operation queue are being called. (I'm saying this by putting NSLog within all selector methods).

I want to know some more details to check/examine the state of each threads.

That is,

- Can I measure the time taken by the selectors to complete?
- Can I know the current state of the particular thread?

It will be very helpful if you added some more points about thread optimization.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: go through the threading documentation provided by Apple http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get thread execution status by invoking the methods like,
– isExecuting
– isFinished
– isCancelled which returns bool.

[also have a look at this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Currently the best way to do thread optimization on iOS is to forget about explicit thread management and use Grand Central Dispatch instead. This doesn’t apply in all cases, but if you just call some selectors in background as you write, explicit threading is clearly overkill.

This is how you spin a selector into background with GCD:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self doSomeLongerTask]; // runs in a background thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self reportOperationDone]; // runs on the UI thread
    });
});
```